# Javascript function dosn't works when I work with templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html file with in a javascript code.

```
<div id="star_rating">
    <a id="one">&#9734;</a><a id="two">&#9734;</a><a id="three">&#9734;</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $("#one").hover(
        function () {
            markHover("true", "false", "false", "false", "false");
        },function () {
            markHover("false", "false", "false", "false", "false");
        }               
    );
    $("#two").hover(
        function () {
            markHover("true", "false", "false", "false", "false");
        },function () {
            markHover("false", "false", "false", "false", "false");
        }               
    );
});
```

Well this works. Now I use a jQuery template system. In the index.html is the script tag included. In a other file that include with a `.on("pagebefore")` event, I include the three `a` tag's. The problem is that the `.hover` function doesn't works. When I paste the `.hover` code in my console it works.

Here the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXPt9/)

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what is not working. Stars show up as expected. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi it doesn't works when I split the js and html in other files.

Comment: I would guess that you're binding the events before the elements exist in the DOM. Try using event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because the elements are created dynamically

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','#one',function () {
    markHover("true", "false", "false", "false", "false");
}).on('mouseleave', '#one', function () {
    markHover("false", "false", "false", "false", "false");
});
$(document).on('mouseenter','#two',function () {
    markHover("true", "true", "false", "false", "false");
}).on('mouseleave', '#two', function () {
    markHover("false", "false", "false", "false", "false");
});
```

You can simplify it to

```
var params = {
    'one': ["true", "false", "false", "false", "false"],
    'two': ["true", "true", "false", "false", "false"],
    'three': ["true", "true", "true", "false", "false"],
    'four': ["true", "true", "true", "true", "false"],
    'five': ["true", "true", "true", "true", "true"],
}

$(document).on('mouseenter','#one, #two, #three, #four, #five',function () {
    markHover.apply(window, params[this.id]);
}).on('mouseleave', '#one, #two, #three, #four, #five', function () {
    markHover("false", "false", "false", "false", "false");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T7jgX/)

Comment: that is a famous answer :) really thumps up for this :) thanks man, I have worked on this since 3 hours.. but now :D really thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Way too much code, not sure why it isn't working with your template but try this:

jQuery:

```
   $(".rate").hover(
        function () {
            var thisone = parseInt($(this).data('star'));
            $(".rate").each(function(){ 
                if(parseInt($(this).data('star')) <= thisone)
                {
                    $(this).html("&#9733;");
                }
            });
        },
        function () {
            $(".rate").each(function(){
                $(this).html("&#9734;");
            });
        }               
    );
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="rate" id="one" data-star="1">&#9734;</a>
    <a class="rate" id="two" data-star="2">&#9734;</a>
    <a class="rate" id="three" data-star="3">&#9734;</a>
    <a class="rate" id="four" data-star="4">&#9734;</a>
    <a class="rate" id="five" data-star="5">&#9734;</a>
</div>
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/uXPt9/3/

Comment: Ha, such is life, glad you got it sorted!